# roscd: No such package/stack 'turtle'

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the Navigating the ROS file system tutorial and have followed the prior tutorials in order. Everything has worked correctly until the step

```
roscd turtle
```

returns

```
roscd: No such package/stack 'turtle'
```

This command was run from /opt/ros/melodic/share/roscpp_tutorials directory. I am in that directory as a result of following the prior commands.

Operating system: Ubuntu 18.04, kernel  4.15.0-45-generic
ROS version: melodic

Tutorial link: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/NavigatingTheFilesystem

`env | grep ROS`  produces the following:

```
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/melodic/etc/ros
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/melodic/share/ros
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_VERSION=1
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=2
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/melodic/share
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=
ROS_DISTRO=melodic
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317214/roscd:-no-such-package/stack-%27turtle%27/) by [willydlw](https://answers.ros.org/users/40281/willydlw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-03-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [phil123456](https://answers.ros.org/users/51234/phil123456/) on 2020-02-07**:
I was fooled too, would be interesting to add this explanation in the doc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

They aren't asking you to run `roscd turtle`... They are demonstrating how TAB completion works. They want you to type `roscd turtle` and then hit TAB twice to see all packages that start with the word `turtle`. They eventually want you to run `roscd turtlesim/` which should change directory to the turtlesim package's root directory.

The "No such package/stack" error is because you are trying to change to the root directory of a package called `turtle`, but there is no package called `turtle`.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2019-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [willydlw](https://answers.ros.org/users/40281/willydlw/) on 2019-03-01**:
Guess I should have been more patient. I type roscd turtle and press the tab key once, nothing happens. I then hit the enter key and got that message. If I press the tab key twice I do get the list. Your answer helped me to be more patient and pay closer attention. Thank you.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2019-03-01**:
Glad everything worked out! If your question is answered, it would be great if you marked this as the correct answer.